# Is there a way to evaluate the accuracy or misclassification rate of the linear model that the R package MatchIt uses to build propensity scores?

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

```
m1.out <- matchit(Treatment ~ co_variate_1 + co_variate_2 + co_variate_3,
                  data = mydata, method = "nearest", ratio = 1)

summary(m1.out)
```

[image]

I am currently using the MatchIt package to do Propensity Score Matching. However, I am not sure if the linear model MatchIt uses is sufficiently accurate, since it directly outputs the control and treatment groups.

In this code, the summary function merely provides the details of how many treated units were matched, along with pre-matching and post-matching differences-in-means of the co-variates.

However, can I get the Accuracy or the confusion matrix for the linear model that the matchit function used to generate the propensity scores?
Basically, how do I know I can trust this matching analysis?

Comment: The quality of the model used to estimate the propensity scores is unrelated to its performance in a matching estimator. See [Ho et al. (2007)](https://doi.org/10.1093/pan/mpl013). The goal of matching is to create balance, so assessing balance is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @Noah, this makes sense - the purpose is to achieve balance in the matched groups, not build a predictive model. But then, how do I know if I am using the appropriate co-variates (or not), since I have many co-variates to choose from?

Comment: That's a harder question to answer than I can in a comment. Seek a statistical consultant who has expertise in this method rather than attempting it yourself, or acquire formal training in matching. This is not a method to be attempted with little experience or expertise in this area. You can search for "variable selection in causal inference" for potentially helpful articles.